# Averaging User Input, looping input until negative number is entered

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Average {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        int amtOfNums = 0;
        int input = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter a series of numbers. Enter a negative number to quit.");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int next = scan.nextInt();

        while ((input = scan.nextInt()) > 0) {
            count += input;
            amtOfNums++;
        }
        System.out.println("You entered " + amtOfNums + " numbers averaging " + (count/amtOfNums) + ".");
    }
}
```

This is supposed to be a Java program that takes integers from the user until a negative integer is entered, then prints the average of the numbers entered (not counting the negative number). This code is not counting the first number I enter. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: About the indentation: add 4 white spaces in front of a line of code to indent it. ([Help page about code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting))

Answer (score 1):

Comment out your first `input` (outside the loop), you called it `next`.

```
// int next = scan.nextInt();
```

That takes one input, and does not add it to `count` or add one to `amtOfNums`. But you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks! I was too frustrated to see that.